# I can't get my instructions to line up with my video

Tags: html

I can't get my instructions to line up with my video on this page http://101river.com/record.. . I am using a table... I want the instructions on the right side of page to be parallel with the video. Any help?

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><object id="container" classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="280" height="336" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,40,0"><param name="align" value="middle" /><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" /><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" /><param name="FlashVars" value="contentId=4c729b75614a5" /><param name="quality" value="high" /><param name="wmode" value="opaque" /><param name="src" value="http://videos2.videobloom.com/container.swf" /><param name="name" value="container" /><param name="flashvars" value="contentId=4c729b75614a5" /><param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" /><embed id="container" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="280" height="336" src="http://videos2.videobloom.com/container.swf" name="container" wmode="opaque" quality="high" flashvars="contentId=4c729b75614a5" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" align="middle"></embed></object>

<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
var host = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://secure." : "http://");document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + host + "wufoo.com/scripts/embed/form.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
// ]]></script>

<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
var q7x3p3 = new WufooForm();
q7x3p3.initialize({
'userName':'rlrm',
'formHash':'q7x3p3',
'autoResize':true,
'height':'648'});
q7x3p3.display();
// ]]></script>

<span style="color: #999999;">*All Twounces are subject to objection. </span></td>
<td><span style="font-size: large;"> </span>
<p style="padding-left: 90px;">1. Click “Record”</p>
<p style="padding-left: 90px;">2. Then Click  ”Start Recording”</p>
<p style="padding-left: 90px;">3. Then Click “Stop Recording”</p>
<p style="padding-left: 90px;">4. Then Click “Preview”</p>
<p style="padding-left: 90px;">5. Then Click  ”Save”</p>
<p style="padding-left: 90px;"></p>
<p style="padding-left: 90px;"><a href="http://101river.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/calendar_48.png"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-210" title="calendar_48" src="http://101river.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/calendar_48.png" alt="" width="48" height="48" /></a> <span style="color: #ff0000;">Important!</span> Now... Schedule your Twounce <span style="color: #000000;">below</span>.</p>
<p style="padding-left: 90px;">OR</p>
<p style="padding-left: 90px;"></p>
<p style="padding-left: 90px;"><span style="color: #339966;"><a href="http://101river.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/Phone-e1282592296196.png"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-264" title="Phone" src="http://101river.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/Phone-e1282592296196.png" alt="" width="48" height="48" /></a>*Record by phone at </span><span style="color: #339966;">(702) 52 SHOUT</span></p>
<p style="padding-left: 90px;"><span style="color: #ff0000;">Note: You will still want to schedule your Twounce <span style="color: #3366ff;"><span style="color: #ff0000;">below</span><span style="color: #000000;">.</span></span></span></p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

not the best answer though!!

```
<td><span style="font-size: large;"> </span>
```

to

```
<td valign="top"><span style="font-size: large;"> </span>
```